# Обновление формы с файлом в Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Доброго времени суток!

Я учусь работать с Symfony и построил простейшую форму для добавления в БД. Проблема в том, что при использовании такой же формы при редактировании записи валидатор ругается на то, что файл не может быть найден, пустое поле с файлом или нет. При редактировании записи загрузка файла по сути не должна быть обязательной, поэтому добавил новую опцию в FormType, но всё равно ошибка :(

**ProjectsController:**

```php
   /**
     * @Route("/projects/{id}/edit", name="project_edit", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function edit($id, Request $request) {
        $project = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Project::class)
            ->find($id);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $form = $this->createForm(ProjectType::class, $project, ['require_photo' => false]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $project = $form->getData();

            if ($request->files->get('photo')) {
                $filesystem = new Filesystem();
                $path = $this->getParameter('photos_directory') . '/' . $project->getPhoto();
                $filesystem->remove($path);

                $file = $form['photo']->getData();
                $fileName = uniqid() . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('photos_directory'),
                    $fileName
                );

                $project->setPhoto($fileName);
            }

            $em->persist($project);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Das Projekt wurde erfolgreich erschafft!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('projects', [
            ]);
        }
```

**ProjectEntity.php**

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProjectRepository")
 */
class Project
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Image(maxSize="5000k")
     */
    private $photo;

    ...

    public function getPhoto(): ?string
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }

    public function setPhoto(?string $photo): self
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**ProjectType:**

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
        ]);
        $builder->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
            'empty_data' => 'Beschreibung',
        ]);
        $builder->add('site', TextType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
            'empty_data' => 'Website'
        ]);
        $builder->add('photo', FileType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'custom-file-input'],
            'required' => $options['require_photo'],
            'mapped' => false,
        ]);
        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Projekt erstellen',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-success']
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Project::class,
            'require_photo' => true,
        ]);

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('require_photo', 'bool');
    }
```

**edit.html.twig**

```
<div class="custom-file">
        {{ form_widget(form.photo) }}
        {{ form_label(form.photo, 'Das Foto des Projektes', {
            'label_attr': {'class': 'custom-file-label'},
        }) }}

        {{ form_errors(form.photo) }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в **`ProjectType`**, нужно было добавить `contraints` для билдера поля с файлом, и удалить валидацию файла в `Entity` и `validator.yaml`

```php
$builder->add('photo', FileType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'custom-file-input'],
            'required' => $options['require_photo'],
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new Image([
                    'maxSize' => '5000k'
                ])
            ]
        ]);
```